# Can't use Python because of some error homebrew.pth

Tags: python-2.7, path, homebrew

Whenever I try to run python, I get this error relating to my path.

```
FrankieMacBook-Pro-2~$ python
Error processing line 2 of /Users/Frankie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1
      import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages") mkdir -p /Users/Frankie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
                                                                                 ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Remainder of file ignored
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I've been using Python3 which doesn't have this issue for me, but now I have a task where I need to use Python2, so need to face this issue.

Any ideas what my issue is?
Did I somehow screw  up my path with homebrew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the Python interpreter runs `site.py` on startup. It is importing `homebrew.pth` and the copy of this file in your 2.7 installation is mangled.

Find this file and either delete it or use a text editor to take this code

```
mkdir -p /Users/Frankie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
```

out of the line that begins

```
import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
```

If you get further syntax errors after doing this, look at the `^` in the syntax error message. It will point to anything else the interpreter does not like.

Comment: Thanks for an incredble answer!! I Just deleted homebrew.pth and it seems fixed.